# Как правильно перезаписать state для массива обьектов?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Иницилизация обьектов

```
ype Result = number
interface Answer {
    result: Result[]
}
const answers: Answer[] = [];

questions.forEach(()=>{ // сразу же инициализируем массив объектов. Каждый объект имеет лишь одно свойство - массив выбранхы пользователем ответов. Если он пуст -> пользователь
    answers.push({      // еще не ответил на этот вопрос. [...answers, result:[]]
        result:[]
    });
})
```

Массив answers выглядит так

```
[{result:[]},{result:[]},{result:[]},{result:[]}]
```

Создание хука

```
const [currentAnswer, setNewAnswer] = useState<Answer[]>(answers);
```

То что я пробовал:

1)

```
 currentAnswer[currentQuestion].result.push(Number(e.target.id));
 setNewAnswer(currentAnswer);
```

2. 

```
let newValue = currentAnswer[currentQuestion].result;
        newValue.push(Number(e.target.id));
        console.log(newValue)
        setNewAnswer({...currentAnswer[currentQuestion], newValue}) //ругается на тип newValue
//Argument of type '{ newValue: number[]; result: number[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Answer[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'newValue' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<Answer[]>'
```

Стейт перезаписывается, но при этом перерисовка не происходит, думаю, дело в том, что обьекты работают иначе. Подскажите как правильно реализовать эту часть

Answer (score 0):

Во первых прочтите внимательнее данную статью: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
Без неё вам будет тяжко.
!!! Нельзя менять стейт напрямую. Вы должны менять новое значение и полностью перезаписывать старое
Во вторых: У вас переменная называется currentAnswer (нынешний ответ), а вы даёте туда массив ответов. Если вы хотите хранить именно один ответ, то делайте так

```
(value) => setNewAnswer(value);
```

Как я понял вам нужно просто хранить выбранный ответ, т.е т.к выше.
Если это обычный ReactJS,то вы можете сделать это через селект

```
answers.map((item, i) => {
    // тут уже сами можете использовать это как для проверки на активность
    let selected = (i === item.id ? true : false;

    return (
        <option key={i} value={item.id} onClick={() => setAnswer(item.id)}>{item.name}</option>
)
```